# Cookies are not stored / delete

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, cookies

I’m working on an IOS app that has a login feature based on cookies and using NSHTTPCookieStorage.
Everything works well while using WIFI and I can login / Logout and cookies are stored and sent
Back to the server.

Once I change from WIFI to 3G/4G something causes the cookies to stop being stored / deleted.
I can’t login nor logout once using 3G/4G. Moving back to WIFI solves the problem.

Even if I manage to get a cookie after login, it’s gone after an app restart when I’m using 3G/4G.
This is not a session cookie and the same cookie (set for 1 year) stays in place when using WIFI.

I'm using AFNetworking.
Any idea would be highly welcome.

Answer (score 0):

```
  NSHTTPCookieStorage* cookies = [NSHTTPCookieStorage   sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
   NSArray* instagramCookies = [cookies cookiesForURL:[NSURL   URLWithString:@"https://instagram.com/"]];
     for (NSHTTPCookie* cookie in instagramCookies)
{
       [cookies deleteCookie:cookie];
}
```

Comment: Hi Vadher
Thanks you for your answer , but my problem is also the fact that the cookie is not stored after I get it in the first time.